# How to install ubuntu from USB with GRUB pre-installed

Tags: 16.04, grub2, system-installation, live-usb, grub-efi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a system with a NVIDIA graphics card, which doesn't seem to like the nouveau drivers very much. Because of that, to run the installer, I have to use `nomodeset`, which I add through GRUB when booting. After installing Ubuntu completely, when I reboot, I don't boot to GRUB however, but instead I immediately boot to Ubuntu, which crashes the X-server immediately.

I have tried following [these](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) instructions, with the only footnote that I also had to `mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi` to make it work, since I booted the USB stick from EFI.

Is there a way to install ubuntu with GRUB properly functioning on boot, so that I can at least boot using `nomodeset` to then install the proper drivers for NVIDIA?

Comment: Have you tried spamming the left shift key right after POST?

Comment: No, I haven't, what does that do exactly? Is that supposed to force GRUB to load?

Comment: Yeah. GRUB is installed, or else the kernel wouldn't be booting